# Like or favorite a post with unique user using Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I was creating a like system for my website. in this I wanted one user can only like one time for a post. and a post can be liked by many user. Also many user can like many post.

So if I guess it right, It is a many to many reletionship.

in this context,
I create the following table

...   users table:

```
id

name
```

....
    posts table :

```
id

post
```

...post_likes table

id

```
user id
poost_id
```

Now I am having the following model for

user :

```
class User extends SentryUserModel {
    public function post_likes()
    {
        return $this->has_many('Post_like', 'id');
    }
}
```

post :

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function post_likes()
    {
        return $this->has_many('Post_like', 'id');
    }
}
```

post_like :

```
class Post_like extends Eloquent {

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('Post', 'post_id');
    }
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('User', 'user_id');
    }

}
```

now when I am going to insert into the database (for post_likes table) I am getting an error called

```
Illuminate \ Database \ Eloquent \ MassAssignmentException
user_id
```

Also I want to know is there any way to inset into database like

```
$user->like()->save($user); ?????
```

Thank you in advance. Happy coding . \m/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll start with a basic issue, firstly you might want to make sure all your tables are lower case (still as a snake case as well), it's not required but it's ultimately how it's expected to be with Laravel so it makes life easier to keep with that. Also a note to the wise, like Class names, database tables are typically in the singular so user instead of users

Secondly yes you can do an insert with $user->post_likes()->save($debate); as your post_likes method on the user class returns has_many.

Thirdly, your design of the Post_like class is a bit off, you could be better off make it like so:

```
class PostLike extends Eloquent { // note that PostLikes is a more standard naming for a class, they should ideally be camel case names but with all capitals for words

    protected $table = 'post_like'; // specifies the table the model uses

    public function post() // this should be singular, the naming of a belngs_to method is important as Laravel will do some of the work for you if let it
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('Post'); // by naming the method 'post' you no longer need to specify the id, Laravel will automatically know from the method name and just adding '_id' to it.
    }
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongs_to('User');
    }

}
```

Fourthly, your other classes could be better as:

```
class Post extends Eloquent {

    public function post_likes()
    {
        return $this->has_many('PostLike'); // doesn't require you to specify an id at all
    }
}
```

I can't exactly tell you why you're getting that mass assign error, your post is a bit garbled and doesn't look like you've included the code that actually causes the exception? I have a feeling though is that you're trying to do an insert for multiple database rows at one time but haven't defined a fillable array for PostLike such as with here: http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Thank you for your awesome answer. It was helpful. But still I am into the problem. like I have changed things according to you. 

`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::has_many()` this error is displayed there..

I have used `$user1->post_likes()->save($debate);`

to save it to the database.

In the last code you mensioned `return $this->has_many('PostLike');`
I have used `return $this->has_many('Post_Like');`

PS : yes I have changed the words while posting here. I have used debate instead post in my database.

Comment: Yes solved this error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::has_many()` as I am using LARAVEL 4 it should be `hasMany()`.

But I am having this error : `Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given, called in E:\xampp\htdocs\ffdd\app\controllers\DebatelikesController.php on line 72 and defined`

and in line 72 the code goes like this `$user1->debate_likes()->save($debate);`

Comment: congrats, was going to say it's possibly that you were putting the table name instead of the class. But glad I could help, also the reason for your possible MassAssignmentException is if you use something like Model::create(array of row values) then it'll through this, instead you should use: $model = new Model(), $model->save() which will do the insert for you singularly

Comment: Friend at this moment I am using `$user1->debate_likes()->save($debate);` to save into the database and it is giving the following error ... 
`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given, called in E:\xampp\htdocs\ffdd\app\controllers\DebatelikesController.php on line 72 and defined`

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing how you're initialising the $debate variable, I've also not seen any previous code about the Debate model, the method you're using is correct in the terms of how it can be used.

Comment: here i am posting the code :

`<?php

class Debate_like extends Eloquent {

 protected $table = 'post_like';

 public function debate()
 {
  return $this->belongs_to('Debate');
 }
 public function users()
 {
  return $this->belongs_to('User');
 }

}
`

---------------

`
class User extends SentryUserModel {
public function debate_likes()
 {
  return $this->hasMany('Debate_like');
 }
}
`
----------------------
`class Debate extends Eloquent {
 protected $guarded = array();

 public static $rules = array();



 public function debate_likes()
 {
  return $this->has_many('Debate_like');
 }

}
`

Comment: Here is my gist :

[the code sample](https://gist.github.com/beingsagir/e1cb7e7c5d5e18aa5c1e)

Comment: sorry that doesn't show me how you're creating an instance of the Debate model or what you're going with it before saving it which is the cause of the exception being thrown.

Comment: i am sorry friend . Now I have added the show method which receive the id of debate to be liked in this [gist comment](https://gist.github.com/beingsagir/e1cb7e7c5d5e18aa5c1e)

Comment: I've commented on your gist instead of here as ultimately this is going further than the original question you asked.

Comment: thank you for your awesome help brother, but still I am struct on an issue : with error, I have mension the full edte code in this new gist. please can you check it.

[The new gist](https://gist.github.com/beingsagir/ad77a277d7ef558966e2)

Answer (score 0):

According to Laravel 5:

**User Model:**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model {
    public function post_likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostLike');
    }
}
```

**Post Model:**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Post extends Model {

    public function post_likes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostLike');
    }
}
```

**PostLike Model:**

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class PostLike  extends Model {

    protected $table = 'post_like';

    public function posts()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
    }
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

and if you want to save the post_like data then:

```
$inputs['post_id'] = 1;
$inputs['user_id'] = 4;

$post_like = PostLike::create($inputs);
```

Hope this helps!!